# Get the next or previous item on a list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a page that has a next and previous links based on an index.

I started to do something like this:

```
var nextPage = $("a.selected").next().find('a').attr('href');
window.location = nextPage;
return true;
```

The problems is that this doesn't work if the 'selected' anchor has no children or more siblings. I would like to be able to go to the next immediate link on the parent level and continue like that through the tree. On the example markup, I would like to be able to go to from "Last Item" to "Test" and go to Test children if it has any...

From what I can see I will need to create conditions for every level which doesn't seem reliable. What's the best way to do this?

The markup looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/wQy6Q/

Thanks.

Comment: can you post: for your example the firsts steps.. how should it traverse the first 5 <a>, because cannot understand exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** I understood correctly your requirement:

For your example: iterate through your tree links in this order:

- 1st: Overview of Data
- 2nd: How Parts of Data Work Together
- 3rd: Data example Software
- 4th: How Data Uses Your Internet Connection During Upload
- 5th: Data Stash
- 6th: Web Access to Data
- 7th: Data Mobile App
- 8th: Data Requirements
- 9th: Data Security

so on...

THEN

```
$('a').each(function(index, link) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(link);
    $(link).attr('href'); // href attribute
});
```

(see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQy6Q/13/)

IF NOT let me know so I will remove this answer

**After comment (you can skip the variables for simpler code):**

```
var collection = $('.treeview a');
var needle = $('.treeview a.selected');
var index = collection.index(needle);

if (index !== -1) { // we have a selected link
    var resultLink = $('.treeview a:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')');
    if (resultLink) { // not the last link
        console.log(resultLink.attr('href'));
    } else { // if last link we retrieve the first one (remove this if you don't need this)
        $('.treeview a:first').attr('href');
    }

}
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQy6Q/19/ (IMPORTANT: I moved the selected link to be the second one in the fiddle for test reasons).

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want, I changed it so that it gets the links only inside the div I want. How do I go about opening the link for the 'selected' class + 1 ?. So basically how do I get the value of the link I am currently at (selected) and open the next one? Thanks a lot! 

$('.treeview a').each(function(index, link) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(link);
    $(link).attr('href'); // href attribute
});

Comment: Thanks so much. I made a few adjustments for the last page. This seems to be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the markup, you can use a "data" attribute to retrieve the next anchor.

Markup example :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="test" data-index="1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test" data-index="2">Test 2</a></li>
<ul>
```

Javascript example :

```
var index = $("a.selected").attr('data-index');
var nextPage = $('a[data-index="' + (index + 1) + '"]').attr('href');
window.location = nextPage;
return true;
```

You can also use a css class if you don't want to use an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var selected = $("a.selected");

//find children
var next = selected.find('a:first');

//find next
if(!next.length){
    next = selected.next().find('a:first');
}

//find parent
var parent = selected.parent();
while(!next.length && parent.not('.treeview')){
    var els = parent.find('a');
    var index = els.index(selected);
    console.log(next, parent)
    next = els.filter(':gt(' + index + ')').first();
    parent = parent.parent();
}

if(next.length){
    console.log(next);
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    next.addClass('selected')
}else{
    console.log('finished')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wQy6Q/17/)